# Live Scrolling Stock Ticker

Tags: jquery, feed, horizontal-scrolling, stock, ticker

Looking for a scrolling stock ticker, as seen here: http://www.bloomberg.com/ - preferably run in combination with jQuery liScroller.

How would I go about this? RSS? Any costs involved?

Recommendations welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use a plugin like liScroller to do the ticker for you than that should not be that much of an hassle.

What you have to do before that is to get the content you want the ticker to scroll throw onto the page before you execute the plugin functions.

I'm not sure what information you want to get, but its likely you can get in on an RSS feed.

You can use jquery to parse the rss feed, sins rss is just an xml file. Here are the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will most certainly use jquery.parseXML, but I need access to the live XML data, or RSS.

Comment: Please forgive, I am not experienced in XML/RSS - where can I access this live stream of data for FTSE 100